# how to handle call to method getElementsByTagname is null

Tags: html, xml, ajax

i have this js piece of code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var sendReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
    var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
    var lastMessage = 0;
    var mTimer;
    function handleReceiveChat() 
    {
       if (receiveReq.readyState == 4)
       {
          var chat_div = document.getElementById('div_chat');    
          var xmldoc = receiveReq.responseXML;     
          var message_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message");
          //more code
       }
    }


    function getChatText()
    {
        if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) 
        {
           receiveReq.open("GET", 'getChat_xml.php?chat=1&last=' + lastMessage, true);
           receiveReq.onreadystatechange = handleReceiveChat; 
           receiveReq.send(null);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and in getChat_xml i have this:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><root>';
if(!isset($_GET['chat'])) 
{
$xml .='Your are not currently in a chat session.  <a href="">Enter a chat session here</a>';
$xml .= '<message id="0">';
$xml .= '<user>Admin</user>';
$xml .= '<text>Your are not currently in a chat session.  &lt;a href=""&gt;Enter a chat session here&lt;/a&gt;</text>';
$xml .= '<time>' . date('h:i') . '</time>';
$xml .= '</message>';
}
else
{
$last = (isset($_GET['last']) && $_GET['last'] != '') ? $_GET['last'] : 0;
$sql = "SELECT message_id, user_name, message, date_format(post_time, '%h:%i') as post_time" . 
    " FROM message WHERE chat_id = " . db_input($_GET['chat']) . " AND message_id > " . $last;
$message_query = db_query($sql);
//Loop through each message and create an XML message node for each.
while($message_array = db_fetch_array($message_query))
    {
    $xml .= '<message id="' . $message_array['message_id'] . '">';
    $xml .= '<user>' . htmlspecialchars($message_array['user_name']) . '</user>';
    $xml .= '<text>' . htmlspecialchars($message_array['message']) . '</text>';
    $xml .= '<time>' . $message_array['post_time'] . '</time>';
    $xml .= '</message>';
}
}
$xml .= '</root>';
```

can anybody help here please?? dont understand how this works
thanks

Comment: You never stated what the problem actually is, as it pertains to the code you posted.

Comment: i am trying to get this tutorial to work on my development box..
  http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Driven_Web_Chat-271_290_291.html

and am encountering an error on line with the message_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message"); cannot call method getElementsByTagName of null???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the code you have posted, these problems come to mind...

1. You have not actually added an `echo $xml;` to output the generated XML.
2. Even after adding an 'echo' statement, you may get `null` `responseXML` (and hence an undefined `getElementsByTagName`) because of some errors in your PHP code (maybe the SQL query).
3. Even if your PHP code is right, you will get `null` `responseXML` because u have not sent proper content header (`header('Content-Type: text/xml');`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid question but are you actually `echo`ing `$xml`  in your `getChat_xml.php` file? I can see `xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message")` returning `null` because it can't find any `<message>` elements because the DOM was never outputted by PHP. What happens when you view the file directly? : http://www.yoursite.com/getChat_xml.php?chat=1&last=xxx

Comment: yikes i get a server error...i have no idea how this works..i am working through a tutorial and am testing it on a dev box, tried to mail the author but email address does not exist anymore..tutorial is at: http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Driven_Web_Chat-271_290_291.html

some help please? thank you

Comment: The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/getChat_xml.php?chat=1&last=0. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly. http error 500...

Comment: 1. i do echo $xml, just after the closing <root> tag
2. what is xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message") suppose to refer to? the message tag in the xml doc??? and it is not finding it??

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark here, but try this:

```
function handleReceiveChat() 
{
   if (receiveReq.readyState == 4)
   {
      var chat_div = document.getElementById('div_chat');    
      var xmldoc = receiveReq.responseXML;     
      var message_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message");

      if (message_nodes)
      {
          //more code
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: i get en error on the line var message_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message");
the thing is it does not find the getElementsByTagName "message"
i  have an xml piece of code where it is defined in another .php file, and the error says cannot call method getElementsByTagName of null?? how can i fix this part please?